# How to take multiple images value and push array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, foreach, base64

I want to do a multiple file upload and I have to convert an image into base64 encoded string. I have one form and two form fields, like firstname & image upload. Suppose a user enters his name and he will upload two photos and he will click submit means, I want convert these two images into base64 string and I want to make my expected JSON format, I don't where I have to change from this code, please anyone update my code

```js
var abc = 0;      // Declaring and defining global increment variable.
$(document).ready(function() {
  //  To add new input file field dynamically, on click of "Add More Files" button below function will be executed.
  $('#add_more').click(function() {
    $(this).before($("<span/>", {
      id: 'filediv'
    }).fadeIn('slow').append($("<input/>", {
      name: 'file[]',
      type: 'file',
      id: 'file'
     }), $(" ")));
   });


   // Following function will executes on change event of file input to select different file.
   $('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
     if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
       abc += 1; // Incrementing global variable by 1.
       var z = abc - 1;
       var x = $(this).parent().find('#previewimg' + z).remove();
       $(this).before("<span id='abcd" + abc + "' class='abcd'><img id='previewimg" + abc + "' src=''/></span>");
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
       reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
       $(this).hide();
       $("#abcd" + abc).append($("<img/>", {
         id: 'img',
         src: 'x.png',
         alt: 'delete'
       }).click(function() {
         $(this).parent().parent().remove();
       });
     )
   });
});


// To Preview Image
function imageIsLoaded(e) {
  $('#previewimg' + abc).attr('src', e.target.result);
};

// Form Submit
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();

var firstName = $("#firstName").val();

var json ={
"rentProperty": 
    {
    "fname" : firstName,
    },
 "gallery":"not loaded yet"

}
var floor_image;
var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file").files;
 if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
   var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

   var fileReader = new FileReader();

   fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
  floor_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; 
  json.gallery=({"image": floor_image });
   }
   fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
 }
console.log(json); 

});

});
```

```css
 @import "http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans";
    form{
    background-color:#fff
    }
    #maindiv{
    width:960px;
    margin:10px auto;
    padding:10px;
    font-family:'Droid Sans',sans-serif
    }
    #formdiv{
    width:500px;
    float:left;
    text-align:center
    }
    form{
    padding:40px 20px;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px;
    border-radius:2px
    }
    h2{
    margin-left:30px
    }
    .upload{
    background-color:red;
    border:1px solid red;
    color:#fff;
    border-radius:5px;
    padding:10px;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 green;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
    }
    .upload:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#c20b0b;
    border:1px solid #c20b0b;
    box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.75)
    }
    #file{
    color:green;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px dashed #123456;
    background-color:#f9ffe5
    }
    #upload{
    margin-left:45px
    }
    #noerror{
    color:green;
    text-align:left
    }
    #error{
    color:red;
    text-align:left
    }
    #img{
    width:17px;
    border:none;
    height:17px;
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-bottom:91px
    }
    .abcd{
    text-align:center
    }
    .abcd img{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #e8debd
    }
    b{
    color:red
    }
```

```html
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
    <div id="maindiv">
    <div id="formdiv">
    <h2>Multiple Image Upload Form</h2>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name ="firstName" id="firstName"><br><br><br>


    <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"  multiple/></div>
    <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

> My Expected answer should come like this

```
{
"rentProperty": 
    {
    "fname" : firstName,
    },
"gallery": [
        {
            "image": "data:image/png/base64.ibokjnerkjdjflkdasafsdnmj........"
        },
        {
            "image": "data:image/jpg/base64.ibokjnerkjdjflkdasafsdnmj........"
        }
],
}
```

> I tried like this

```
$('#upload').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var firstName = $("#firstName").val();

var floor_image;
var filesSelected = document.getElementById("file").files;
    if (filesSelected.length > 0) {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[0];

      var fileReader = new FileReader();

      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent) {
        floor_image = fileLoadedEvent.target.result; 
        json.gallery=({"image": floor_image });
      }
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
    }

var json ={
"rentProperty": 
    {
    "fname" : firstName,
    },
    "gallery":"not loaded yet"

}
console.log(json); 

});
```

> I am getting answer like this

```
{
"rentProperty": 
    {
    "fname" : firstName,
    },
"gallery": 
        {
            "image": "data:image/png/base64.ibokjnerkjdjflkdasafsdnmj........"
        }
}
```

I think i have to foreach loop and i have to push in to one array, but i am not sure if anyone know means update my answer

Comment: Hi this is a nice tools but, you got a problem in this situation, first if people want to upload in one step a multi select image as you expect using **name="file[]" is multi select mode**, this situation from the folder mode select can select multiples files for the future upload. The button add new upload is depreciate in this situation and your tool can't do the job. So **if you want to upload only one file during the select image from the folder use name="file_"+i**  for example but *No name="file[]*".

Answer (score 0):

You need an array. Just change this string:

```
json.gallery=({"image": floor_image });
```

to

```
json.gallery[]=({"image": floor_image });
```